How to minimize queries when recalculating route?
We use Directions API but a single route recalculation can generate up to 2000 queries, it is too expensive, how can it be optimized?
We removed route recalculation and lowered the number of queries but still the route alone can generate 300 queries from point A to point B.



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jump to Element</title>
    <script>
        function jumpToSecond() {
            var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[id="toSection"]');
            
            if (elements.length > 1) {
                elements[1].scrollIntoView();
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="toSection">First occurrence of toSection</p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="jumpToSecond();">Click to jump to second toSection</a>
    <p id="toSection">Second occurrence of toSection</p>
</body>
</html>




Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

Please note that Stack Overflow doesn't work like a discussion forum, so please avoid salutations and the like. Only text that is strictly related to the solution should be added. For more information: Why are fellow users removing thank-you's from my questions?.

This has nothing to do with the question. Please delete.
